# Postgresql: Выбор N первых групп в запросе

Tags: postgresql

Нужно ограничить выборку в запросе количеством групп.

```
create table t (a integer, b text);
insert into t values (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (10, 'b'), (11, 'b'), (0, 'c');
```

Мне нужно отсортировать по b и выдать 2 записи по двум первым b (ф);

```
select * from t order by b;
 a  | b 
----+---
  1 | a
  2 | a
  3 | a
 10 | b
 11 | b
 -- лимит нужно поставить здесь
  0 | c
(6 rows)
```

Помогла бы оконная функция `count(distinct b) over (order by b)` но ее нет. Сделать хочется без подзапроса `where b in (select distinct(b) from t order by b limit 2)`. В реальности там не таблица, а сложный джойн.

Answer (score 0):

Ответили на англоязычном форуме:

```
select * from (
   select *,dense_rank() over (order by  b) group_number  from t order by b
) a where group_number<=2
```